# JedisPool memory leak

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, redis, jedis

I use jedisPool on production environment. When I start the server to process request, redis pool just works fine. But after a while, the log file start to telling me that : 'JedisException: Could not get a resource from the pool.'
  Here is my config :

```
redis.maxIdle=200
redis.minIdle=20
redis.maxWaitMillis=1000
redis.maxTotal=2000
redis.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
```

and here is my code :

```
    public static String getStr(String key) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(key))
        return null;

    JedisPool readPool = null;
    Jedis jedis = null;
    try {
        String redisKey = makeKey(key);
        readPool = getJedisPool();
        jedis = readPool.getResource();
        return jedis.get(redisKey);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("occurs exception", ex);
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (jedis != null && pool != null) {
        jedis.close();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this scenery is caused by jedis instance memory leak because the log file continue to logging the same error. I have to restart the server to stopping it.
  Is there anyone can tell me where the memory leak has happend? Or I miss some important config?

Answer (score 0):

Both `JedisPool` and `Jedis` are `Closeable`, but you only close `Jedis` and never close the pool. Probably this is what causes your problem.

Assuming you have Java 7 or higher, try this:

```
String redisKey = makeKey(key);

try (JedisPool readPool = getJedisPool();
     Jedis jedis = readPool.getResource()) {

    return jedis.get(redisKey);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.warn("occurs exception", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

The above will close the pool, obviously, so in case when your pool is shared among several consumers it might not be the best idea, so another approach should be taken.

According to Jedis sources, it uses Apache's GeneridObjectPool internally. These pools require clients to return resources back into pools after you're done with them, as captured in docs to [borrowObject](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject--):

> By contract, clients **must** return the borrowed instance using ObjectPool.returnObject(T), ObjectPool.invalidateObject(T), or a related method as defined in an implementation or sub-interface.

In Jedis, there is an analog to `returnObject`call for their pool, `returnResourceObject(T)` method:

```
String redisKey = makeKey(key);
JedisPool readPool = getJedisPool();
Jedis jedis = null;

try {
  jedis = readPool.getResource();
  return jedis.get(redisKey);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  log.warn("occurs exception", ex);
  throw ex;
}
finally {
  if (jedis != null) {
    jedis.close(); // actually, since you return it, may be not needed.      
    readPool.returnResourceObject(jedis);
  }
}
```

Comment: But jedisPool is a singleton, why should I close it after I get a jedis instance ?

Comment: @mutou, the actual exception according to Jedis sources is exception in `borrowObject` from [underlying pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject--). Since there's no further implementation details on what that pool is and how it is populated, I think suggesting to close the pool is valid.

Comment: @mutou, I actually found the possible reason for your problem. Will update my answer.